# Issue granting consent to access AppInsights Data

Tags: azure-active-directory, appinsights, azure-monitor

We have too many instances of AppInsights configured, so I am trying to determine the most-recent log entry in each instance to learn which are no longer being used.  Here is my code.

```
namespace EnumerateAppInsights
{
    using Azure;
    using Azure.Core;
    using Azure.Identity;
    using Azure.Monitor.Query;
    using Azure.Monitor.Query.Models;
    using Azure.ResourceManager;
    using Azure.ResourceManager.ApplicationInsights;
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredential(username, password, tenantId, clientId);

            try
            {
                var armClient = new ArmClient(credentials);

                var subscriptionCollection = armClient.GetSubscriptions();
                foreach (var subscriptionResource in subscriptionCollection.GetAll())
                {
                    foreach (var resourceGroup in subscriptionResource.GetResourceGroups())
                    {
                        var appInsightsCollection = resourceGroup.GetApplicationInsightsComponents();
                        foreach (var appInsightsComponentResource in appInsightsCollection.GetAll())
                        {
                            var queryClient = new LogsQueryClient(credentials);

                            string resourceId =    
                                $"/subscriptions/{subscriptionResource.Data.SubscriptionId}" +
                                $"/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup.Data.Name}" +
                                $"/providers/Microsoft.Insights/AppInsights" +
                                $"/{appInsightsComponentResource.Data.Name}";

                            Response<LogsQueryResult> results = await queryClient.QueryResourceAsync(
                                new ResourceIdentifier(resourceId),
                                WebUtility.UrlEncode("traces | top 1 by timestamp desc | project timestamp"),
                                new QueryTimeRange(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)));
                                ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output.

```
Error: UsernamePasswordCredential authentication failed: 
AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with 
ID '3d5d70e8-2249-4979-b5ea-6892e9a7ce4e' named 'EnumerateAppInsights'. 
Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
```

I was originally receiving this exception from the `ArmClient()` but solved that problem by adding `Api Permissions & Admin Consent` for `Azure Server Management` to the App Registration.

But now I am getting it from the `LogsQueryClient()` and even after adding permissions/consent for:

- Applications Insight
- API Azure Analysis Services
- Azure DevOps

it's still happening.  Anyone have any thoughts to share?

Adding the missing permissions - Log Analytics API - solved this problem.  But now I am getting "SEM0100": Failed to resolve table expression named 'traces'".  Is it possible this is because we have not yet updated to Workspace-based Application Insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if the service principal does not have required **permissions** or **roles** to perform the operation.

I registered one Azure AD application and added below **`API permissions`** by granting **admin consent** like this:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment, I too got **same error** as you like below:

```cs
namespace EnumerateAppInsights
{
    using Azure;
    using Azure.Core;
    using Azure.Identity;
    using Azure.Monitor.Query;
    using Azure.Monitor.Query.Models;
    using Azure.ResourceManager;
    using Azure.ResourceManager.ApplicationInsights;
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredential(username, password, tenantId, clientId);

            try
            {
                var armClient = new ArmClient(credentials);

                var subscriptionCollection = armClient.GetSubscriptions();
                foreach (var subscriptionResource in subscriptionCollection.GetAll())
                {
                    foreach (var resourceGroup in subscriptionResource.GetResourceGroups())
                    {
                        var appInsightsCollection = resourceGroup.GetApplicationInsightsComponents();
                        foreach (var appInsightsComponentResource in appInsightsCollection.GetAll())
                        {
                            var queryClient = new LogsQueryClient(credentials);

                            string resourceId =    
                                $"/subscriptions/{subscriptionResource.Data.SubscriptionId}" +
                                $"/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup.Data.Name}" +
                                $"/providers/Microsoft.Insights/AppInsights" +
                                $"/{appInsightsComponentResource.Data.Name}";

                            Response<LogsQueryResult> results = await queryClient.QueryResourceAsync(
                                new ResourceIdentifier(resourceId),
                                WebUtility.UrlEncode("traces | top 1 by timestamp desc | project timestamp"),
                                new QueryTimeRange(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)));
                                ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to add **Log Analytics API** permission in your application as below:

[image]

Make sure to grant **admin consent** to added API permissions as below:

[image]

When I ran the same code again after granting consent to above permission, I got **response** like this:

[image]

In your case, make sure to add **Log Analytics API** permission and grant **admin consent** for it to resolve the error.

**Reference:**
[API access and authentication - Azure Monitor | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/access-api)

Comment: Thanks - adding Log Analytics API permission & consent solved my problem.